# creating XML in T-SQL with multiple attributes

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql

Would like to ask how to create xml doc in T SQL which looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root firstAttribute="test" secondAttribute="test" etc...>
   <order firstAttribute="test" secondAttribute="test" etc...></order>
</root>
```

I don't really know how to insert multiple argumets.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use **FOR XML to Convert the table to the XML format **

```
SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM Customers 
inner join Orders  on Customers.CustomerID= Orders.CustomerID 
FOR XML AUTO
```

and add string before

```
select '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'  + (
SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM Customers 
inner join Orders  on Customers.CustomerID= Orders.CustomerID 
FOR XML AUTO  
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will provide you with the logic you need to create xml from a table "TestTable".

```
DECLARE @TestTable table (firstAttribute int, secondAttribute varchar(100))

INSERT INTO @TestTable values (1,'Test 1')
INSERT INTO @TestTable values (2,'Test 2')


SELECT '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'  + (
    SELECT 
           firstAttribute,
           secondAttribute     
    FROM   @TestTable
    FOR XML PATH ('root')

)
```